# Hyperstack doesn't find landing page resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperstack

Hypertext /install guide shows you how to add Hypertext to an existing Rails app.  I've got to the point where I should be able to launch the legacy app as before, but the routes to image resources can't be resolved.  I think I'm just not getting the routes set correctly, on the other hand I haven't changed anything from what the Guide says.  This is a first pass at Hyperstack and it feels like something pretty obvious, but it isn't yielding to the simple tests I've tried so far.

```
routes.rb

    Rails.application.routes.draw do

    mount Hyperstack::Engine => '/hyperstack'  # this route should be first in the routes file so it always matches
```

/hyperstack/hyper_component.rb

```
# app/hyperstack/hyper_component.rb
class HyperComponent
  # All component classes must include Hyperstack::Component
  include Hyperstack::Component
  # The Observable module adds state handling
  include Hyperstack::State::Observable
  # The following turns on the new style param accessor
  # i.e. param :foo is accessed by the foo method
  param_accessor_style :accessors
end
```

/components/shipment.rb

```
class Shipment < HyperComponent

  # param :my_param
  # param param_with_default: "default value"
  # param :param_with_default2, default: "default value" # alternative syntax
  # param :param_with_type, type: Hash
  # param :array_of_hashes, type: [Hash]
  # other :attributes  # collects all other params into a hash
  # fires :callback  # creates a callback param

  # access params using the param name
  # fire a callback using the callback name followed by a !

  # state is kept and read as normal instance variables
  # but when changing state prefix the statement with `mutate`
  # i.e. mutate @my_state = 12
  #      mutate @my_other_state[:bar] = 17

  # the following are the most common lifecycle call backs,
  # delete any that you are not using.
  # call backs may also reference an instance method i.e. before_mount :my_method

  before_mount do
    # any initialization particularly of state variables goes here.
    # this will execute on server (prerendering) and client.
  end

  after_mount do
    # any client only post rendering initialization goes here.
    # i.e. start timers, HTTP requests, and low level jquery operations etc.
  end

  before_update do
    # called whenever a component will be re-rerendered
  end

  before_unmount do
    # cleanup any thing before component is destroyed
    # note timers are broadcast receivers are cleaned up
    # automatically
  end

  render do
    DIV do
      'Shipment'
    end
  end
end
```

Command line from start

```
$ bundle exec foreman start
...
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'client_and_server-e8a2a4c02f7542e3e05c' with type 'application/javascript'
...
```

and later on in the command line,

```
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/assets/stylesheets
16:45:00 web.1        |   /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/bootstrap-4.3.1/assets/javascripts):
16:45:00 web.1        |     10: 
16:45:00 web.1        |     11:  
16:45:00 web.1        |     12:   // search path default is public/images
16:45:00 web.1        |     13:   = image_tag "Drayage-LongBeach.jpg", :size => "520x360" 
16:45:00 web.1        |     14:   %p
16:45:00 web.1        |     15:   %p
16:45:00 web.1        |     16:
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the fact that it can't find your packed manifest file (which was I assume working before) I suspect that you are on webpacker < 4.0.

Webpacker now stores bundles in `/javascripts/js` rather than just `/javscripts/`  and hyperstack installer assumes that.

**Keep Current Version of Webpack**

Go into `config/initializers/assets.rb` and you will see towards the end a line like this

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('public', 'packs', 'js').to_s
```

just remove `, 'js'` and it will work with old webpacker.

There is also a similar line in `config/environments/test.rb` that needs to be modified as well for hyper-spec to work.

**Upgrade Webpack (Recommended - your going to have to do it sooner or later)**

Or you can upgrade webpacker to ~> 4.0.

You will need answer "Y" to both conflicts, then you must also delete `.babelrc` file if it exists, and finally run `bin/webpack`

1. Update your Gemfile
2. `bundle install`
3. `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`  *answer Y to both conflicts*
4. Delete `.babelrc` if it exists
5. Run `bin/webpack`

This should successfully upgrade webpacker to 4.x, and all should now be well.

Comment: I agree, let's go to webpack 4.x.  Ran gem install webpacker -v 4.0.6 and also added a gem for it to Gemfile.  Step 3 however is not happy: ` Acantha:roll365 john$ bundle exec rails webpacker:install
...
LoadError: incompatible library version - /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.2/gems/bindex-0.7.0/lib/skiptrace/cruby.bundle`

Comment: So, it's working after I did a gem pristine --all; then bundle install.  Replaced the ', .js' elements.  This brings us to step 5 which I don't understand (it doesn't seem to be a valid command, is there a webpack cli I missed?).  However the app comes up, .jpg and all.  As Catmandu predicted the routes work but need to be adjusted to go something useful.  Thanks.